# Not able to generate cucumber report basically the mail execution fails

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am not able to generate the email of the cucumber report, it was working fine a few days ago but now it throws the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (mail-execution) on project qa-automation: An exception occured while executing the Java class. no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="featureChartCarousel"]/ol/li[1]"}
[ERROR]   (Session info: headless chrome=108.0.5359.124)
[ERROR] For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#no_such_element
[ERROR] Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
[ERROR] System info: host: 'ip-10-0-1-80', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-1092-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_352'
[ERROR] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
[ERROR] Command: [f0b38831845245c963309f6da8c906c1, findElement {using=xpath, value=//*[@id="featureChartCarousel"]/ol/li[1]}]
[ERROR] Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 108.0.5359.124, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 108.0.5359.71 (1e0e3868ee06..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.WmdU7j}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:32925}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:32925/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 108.0.5359.124, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
[ERROR] Session ID: f0b38831845245c963309f6da8c906c1
```

I checked the XPath is fine but the mail is not getting triggered I think the report is not getting generated